# oracle shows output of select query despite I am spooling the output in a file

Tags: oracle

I am saving the password in a file using below code but while doing that I am also getting that password in the output, which I want to avoid. Please suggest if there is any way we can spool the output and does not print it.

```
set heading off;
spool abc.txt
select password from sys.user$ where username='test';
spool off;

Output:
AH45****mn
```

Comment: Why did you delete [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67807527/266304)?

Answer (score 3):

Add this to the top of your script:

```
set termout off
```

[From the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/SPOOL.html):

> To spool output generated by commands in a script without displaying the output on the screen, use `SET TERMOUT OFF`. `SET TERMOUT OFF` does not affect output from commands that run interactively.

[and](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqpug/tuning-SQL-Plus.html#GUID-8D862F17-FACE-4349-9608-73D105E7A162):

> `SET TERMOUT OFF` suppresses the display so that you can spool output from a script without seeing it on the screen.
>
> If both spooling to file and writing to terminal are not required, use `SET TERMOUT OFF` in SQL scripts to disable terminal output.

If you are running this from SQL Developer with those commands in a worksheet, via 'Run Script (F5)', then it won't honour the `termout` setting properly. But it you save that to a file and then run that, it will; so if you create a file with the commands as, say, `your_script.sql` then in a worksheet you would just have:

```
@your_script
```

or

```
@/path/to/your_script
```

and run that with F5.

In SQL*Plus you can do the same, with `@your_script` from an interactive prompt, or running it directly from the command line (though you might want to add `exit` to the end of the script if you do this):

```
sqlplus @your_script
```

which will prompt for username and password; or

```
sqlplus user @your_script
```

which will just prompt for password. (Or you can supply the password on the command line, but that's not a great idea.)

You can also add the `-s` silent flag:

```
sqlplus -s -l user @your_script
```

That will hide all output including the application banner and the password prompt - it will still wait for you to enter the password, you just won't see a prompt for it. The `-l` flag is useful if you do that; if you get the password wrong it will exit, rather than (silently) waiting for you to re-enter the username and then password.

Comment: I used it like below but still printing password in output:

```spool abc.txt
set termout off
select password from sys.user$ where username='test';
set termout on
spool off;```

Comment: Are you using SQL\*Plus or SQL Developer? With SQL Developer you would need to save the script as a file then run it as `@your_script.sql`

Comment: I am connecting my db from linux server.
in my home directory I have created script test.sql which contains below data.

`spool abc.txt set termout off select password from sys.user$ where username='test'; set termout on spool off` 

Then I am login to database using below command:
`sqlplus username@dbname and the entering password`

the in sql screen I am running the file but still getting the output:

`sql>@test.sql
AH45****mn`

Comment: @Divya - I don't see that behaviour, and never have from SQL\*Plus, on any version I've sued. (I'm also testing this on Linux, with 12.1 client and DB, not that it should matter). You could try `sqlplus username@dbname @test.sql` and enter your password when prompted; you might also want to add `exit` to the end of your script. ANd you can do `sqlplus -s ...` to hide the banner.